# MASM assembly - Why does this code still jump?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Basically Im trying to prompt the user for an integer and test to see if it is unsigned. If it is unsigned i want to move to the unsigned block and get another user input. If it IS signed, then basically just do nothing and end the program.

```
mov edx, OFFSET prompt1  
call writeString         
call readDec  
test eax, eax  
jns unsigned


unsigned:  
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt2   
    call writeString    
    call readDec

END main
```

However, even when i enter in an unsigned integer like -5, it still goes to the unsigned block and runs the code in the block. Why does it still jump even though the input in eax is signed and i am using jump if NOT signed?

Comment: Have you considered putting an `exit` directive right after the `jns` instruction?

Answer (score 5):

When EAX doesn't have the sign bit set the `jns unsigned` instruction jumps to the `unsigned` label an executes the instruction there. When EAX has the sign bit set it doesn't jump and instead executes the following instruction.

In both case the same instruction gets executed: `mov edx, OFFSET prompt2`.  It's both the instruction at the the label `unsigned` and the instruction following the `jns unsigned` instruction.

If you want your program to end if EAX is negative then you'll need to add the some code following the `jns unsigned` instruction that causes it to end. Otherwise it will continue on executing instructions. You run into the same problem at the end of your code. The `END` directive just tells the assembler to stop assembling your code, it doesn't stop the program from executing. After the second `call readDec` returns your program will execute whatever instructions happen to follow it in memory.